# Find Item In Kotlin Arrays Return Null

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having this class

```
class Product(val price: BigDecimal, val tag: String)
```

Then I add items to this class

```
 var products = ArrayList<Product>()

 for (i in 1..5) {
     products.add(Product((0.25 * i).toBigDecimal(), i.toString()))
 }
```

Now I can view the items like this

```
products.forEach {
    Log.d("xxx", "price: ${it.price} tag: ${it.tag}")
}
```

Results:

```
D/xxx: price: 0.25 tag: 1
D/xxx: price: 0.5 tag: 2
D/xxx: price: 0.75 tag: 3
D/xxx: price: 1.0 tag: 4
D/xxx: price: 1.25 tag: 5
```

What I'm trying to do is, find "price" with "tag" = "3" in products.
I'm using this code but it gives me `null`.

```
var f = products.find { it.tag.equals('3') }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is already inside your question.

You are trying to save tag as `"tag" = "3"` but you are trying to retrieve with `it.tag.equals('3')`.

Simply you have to change your code  with `it.tag.equals("3")`

Replace this line

```
var f = products.find { it.tag.equals('3') }
```

with this

```
 var f = products.find { it.tag.equals("3") }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "3" and '3' are different. '3' is the character of the number 3 and "3" is a string that contains the character of 3. By using `equals` function, in fact, you are getting false always in the predicate due to inequality of `String` and `Char` types. So, if you change the code like the following, the problem will be solved:

```
var f = products.find { it.tag == "3" }
```

Note that `==` in kotlin is the operator function of `equals` which makes it simpler to read and write.